# Multiple replace statement on one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update `table_A`. I should remove some characters or words. Table `REPLACE1` has all strings that should be replaced. I am using this statement but it is  taking too long to update this table. Could you recommend me something else?

```
WHILE(SELECT COUNT(a.*) FROM TABLE_A a,REPLACE1 r WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE ('%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(r.REMOVE))+'%'))>0
BEGIN
    UPDATE a
    SET a.column1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, r.REMOVE,' '),'  ','')
    FROM TABLE_A a, REMOVE r 
    WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE ('%'+LTRIM(RTRIM(r.REMOVE))+'%')
END
```

Comment: You can do it all in one statement: `UPDATE a
SET a.column1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(column1, r.REMOVE,' '),'  ','')
FROM TABLE_A a CROSS JOIN REMOVE r`

Comment: i TRIED THIS STATEMENT BUT IS IS NOT WORKING. Wnen I run my query it was running for 10 hours and i canceled it.